# Linear Transformation $T(f) = f + f' + f''$ is injective and/or surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V=C^{\infty}([0,1])$ be the vector space of (infinitely) differentiable functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be the linear transformation $T(f)=f+f'+f''$.

Is $T$ injective? If not, calculate a basis for the null-space.

Is $T$ surjective?

I'm pretty stumped, I think it's injective as I was unable to come up with a counterexample, I think it's surjective as well. I have some ideas about showing that it's injective and surjective using the basis $1,x,x^2,x^3...$ for $V=C^{\infty}([0,1])$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is basically a simple question on ODE's.

Comment: You'll find the kernel of the transformation by solving the ODE $f+f'+f''=0$. See what this gives you, and take it from there.

Comment: So here's an observation: since $T$ involves taking a second derivative, so the kernel obviously contains all affine maps.

Comment: it has non-empty null space so obviously not injective. Surjectivity should come from existence theorem of ODE's.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger:  It seems the kernel contains no affine maps (apart from the $0$-map).  E.g., $T(x)=1+x\neq 0$.

Comment: Woops, I am stupid. There is no sensible way of correcting this comment. My bad. The most charitable interpretation is to say that this suggests a kernel of degree $2$, but this is already clear from the ODEs comment.